# Metals shield electric field. Then why light passes through aluminium foils?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

As light is an electromagnetic wave, it should not be able to pass through a metallic sheet. Then why can light passes through aluminium foils?

Comment: Does light pass through? I've never seen light passing through an aluminium foil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A perfectly conductive material blocks electromagnetic waves perfectly.

But real aluminum is not a perfect conductor. In a material with nonzero resistivity $\rho$, an EM wave with frequency $\omega$ will penetrate, decaying exponentially with characteristic distance $\delta$, called the *skin depth*. In everyday situations, the skin depth is given by

$$\delta = \sqrt{\frac{2\rho}{\omega\mu}}$$

where $\mu$ is the magnetic permeability of the material.

If your aluminum foil is thinner than a small multiple of this skin depth, you'd likely notice some light passing through it under reasonable viewing conditions.

For aluminum, we can estimate $\rho = 2.65\times 10^{-8} {\rm \Omega\cdot m}$ and $\mu = 4\pi\times 10^{-7}\ {\rm H\cdot m^{-1}}$. For visible light at 500 nm we have $\omega=376\times 10^{15}\ {\rm s^{-1}}$. So we get

$$\delta \approx 3.35\times 10^{-9}\ {\rm m}$$

which is a very thin foil indeed (even if we take a limit of perhaps 10 skin depths through which we might be able to detect a slight leakage of light from a strong source into a dark room). But certainly you could see light pass through an aluminum film sputtered onto a sheet of glass, for example.